# How do you interface with a lower version of solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.7.x

I'm trying to create a contract (solidity version 0.7.6) that interacts with some arbitrary contract of a lower version (0.4.21). However, I have been trying to declare an interface in (0.7.6) but it does not seem to be compatible. I am trying to use the interface defined on (0.7.6) to interact with and call functions from the (0.4.21). Assume that the (0.4.21) contract is already deployed. What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks very much for your help and expertise.

Comment: Use Hardhat's [multi-compiler](https://hardhat.org/guides/compile-contracts.html#multiple-solidity-versions) feature.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg no, that's not the issue here.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you have to use the `>=` prefix instead of `^`. But note it is not always possible to do that, you might have to rewrite that contract to adhere to the latest version of Solidity.

Comment: Can you show the interface for the 0.4 contract? It should be possible to update the interface to a 0.7 version backward compatible with 0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example;

```
function invoke(address _target, bytes memory _data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
            // External contracts can be compiled with different Solidity versions
            // which can cause "revert without reason" when called through,
            // for example, a standard IERC20 ABI compiled on the latest version.
            // This low-level call avoids that issue.

            bool success;
            bytes memory _res;
            // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
            (success, _res) = _target.call(_data);
            if (!success && _res.length > 0) {
                // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
                assembly {
                    returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                    revert(0, returndatasize())
                }
            } else if (!success) {
                revert("VM: wallet invoke reverted");
            }
            return _res;
        }
```

The target id the address of the contract you are calling,
The data is the function call and argument encoded like this;

```
 bytes memory _data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "swap(address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256[],uint256)",
                fromToken,
                toToken,
                amount,
                minReturn,
                distribution,
                flag
            );
```